# Detecting escape char in csv

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to determine how to detect if an escape character is being used in a csv, and if so, what that character is. Here is what I have so far:

```
escape_chars = []

if (quote_char is not None)
    if ('"' + quote_char) in csv_text:
        escape_chars.append('"')

if ('\\' + separator) in csv_text:
    escape_chars.append('\\')
```

An example input would be:

```
"first","last"
"Roy","Jones\, Jr."
```

And the function should return:

```
get_escape_char(string)
>>> "\"
```

Does this seem valid? Or is the detecting of escape characters too error-prone to try it this way? If so, is there another method I could use?

Comment: @PedroLobito no I mean for a csv file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open('m.csv') as f:
  x = f.read()
  print [i for i, c in enumerate(x) if c == '\\']
```

will give you the index of all `\` chars in this file